# How to measure L1, L2, L3 cache hits & misses in OSX

Tags: macos, performance, cpu-cache, kernel-extension

I've a C++ program and I would like to quantify it's performance by checking the number of hits and misses against the CPU cache.

What's the best way to do it?

I tried using [Intel's Performance Counter Monitor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor) but it uses an unsigned Kernel Extension which are disabled on Yosemite. I can obviously disable the check to not load unsigned kexts but I wouldn't like to go down that path.

Is there any other possible way that I'm unaware of?

Comment: There's a version of Cachegrind apparently available for OSX. It can measure both cache misses and branch mispredictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can **enable unsigned kernel extensions** with OS X (*reboot afterwards required*):

```
sudo nvram boot-args=kext-dev-mode=1
```

This enables developer mode on your machine and you can run Intel Performance Counter Monitor as long at it supports Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) in general.

**Don't forget to disable it again** after you are done with testing  (security-issue otherwise):

```
sudo nvram boot-args=kext-dev-mode=0
```

As far as I know Intel's tool is far better than cache grind because it uses actual counters from the hardware instead of simulating an cpu and it's cache characteristics in software.

Answer (score 0):

You could, in principle, apply for a kext signing certificate, if you're an Apple developer programme member, and sign the kext yourself. But they generally don't hand them out for internal use, and recommend you enable kext-dev-mode or disable SIP (depending on version). Another good path would be to ask Intel to provide a signed version of their kext!